# Ошибки в консоли при запуске live-server

Tags: javascript, консоль

При запуске live-server для автоматического обновления страницы в консоли всегда появляются три ошибки, причем они присутствуют всегда даже если не написано ни одной строчки кода, данные ошибки ни на что не влияют, они просто всегда появляются всякий раз после перезагрузки страницы, не исчезают и жутко раздражают.

Пытался разобраться самостоятельно, но проблему так и не решил... Прошу вашей помощи и содействия. С чем могут быть связаны данные ошибки и как от них избавиться?

Текст ошибок из консоли:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'onClicked' of undefined
    at stats.js:12

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
    at eval (eval at  (chrome-extension://ildilgiiijjkiadbdcgcdjgeogfbpdkh/js/jqmini.js:9986), :1:48)
    at chrome-extension://ildilgiiijjkiadbdcgcdjgeogfbpdkh/js/jqmini.js:9986
    at chrome-extension://ildilgiiijjkiadbdcgcdjgeogfbpdkh/js/jqmini.js:35
    at chrome-extension://ildilgiiijjkiadbdcgcdjgeogfbpdkh/js/jqmini.js:39

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
    at eval (eval at  (chrome-extension://ildilgiiijjkiadbdcgcdjgeogfbpdkh/js/jqmini3-0-0.js:9987), :1:59)
    at chrome-extension://ildilgiiijjkiadbdcgcdjgeogfbpdkh/js/jqmini3-0-0.js:9987
    at chrome-extension://ildilgiiijjkiadbdcgcdjgeogfbpdkh/js/jqmini3-0-0.js:36
    at chrome-extension://ildilgiiijjkiadbdcgcdjgeogfbpdkh/js/jqmini3-0-0.js:40

Comment: Удалите\отключите расширение `ildilgiiijjkiadbdcgcdjgeogfbpdkh` в хроме.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Проблему вызывало приложение для обхода блокировки RUtracker.org Ошибки исчезли